# JAVA_HOME error while maven build, OSX-10.8.4 Version

Tags: macos, java

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute
  /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java
```

I have upgraded my OSX to 10.8.4. After OSX upgrade I have upgraded my JDK and JRE to 7. But I am getting the above error when I am trying for maven build of project.

When I run `ls -al /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/`

I get the below response

```
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 Jul 22 22:33 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel  340 Jul 22 18:30 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jul 22 18:30 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jul 22 18:30 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jul 22 18:30 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jul 22 18:30 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jul 22 18:30 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Jul 22 18:30 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel  238 Jul 22 18:30 A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1 Jul 22 18:30 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   59 Jul 22 18:30 CurrentJDK -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents
```

For this `ls -al /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin`

I don't see any contents in CurrentJDK further.

On running `/usr/libexec/java_home`

I get:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I am pretty much new to working with OS X. Let me know if I might have missed any point still in making it successful.

Comment: Can you run `echo $JAVA_HOME`, `ls -al /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin` and `ls -al /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/` and add the result to the question?

Comment: @patrix
.bashrc -> `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home` 
.profile -> `export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH` 
`export CATALINA_HOME=/Library/Tomcat/Home` 

.bashrc and .profile has the above commands mentioned in it..

Comment: @Patrix.. I see that the java path is not retrieved from bashrc file. When I set JAVA_HOME from terminal separately only then I could able to build a project. Why could this be happening like this ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 9):

Apple recommends to set JAVA_HOME to “/usr/libexec/java_home“.

What worked for me was wrapping this around $(). So I ended up configuring JAVA_HOME like $(/usr/libexec/java_home) with the following commands:

```
vim ~/.bash_profile 
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: This worked for me perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java` if it exists is the Java supplied by Apple of which the latest version would be a JRE 1.6.

To use the Oracle JDK (the java 7 you mention) use the path /usr/bin/java if you have installed it fully. Note that the JRE is only for Java applets and so does not affect /usr/bin/java

For more information see the Oracle install documentation

and note from there

> To run a different version of Java, either specify the full path, or use the java_home tool:
>
> ```
> /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.0_06 --exec javac -version
> ```
>
> For more information, see the java_home(1) man page.

Comment: .profile ->export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export CATALINA_HOME=/Library/Tomcat/Home

Comment: @arvind what do those comments mean?

Comment: @arvind406 yes but what does that add or ask about my answer?

Comment: previous comments were commented in wrong window. Apologies.

After upgrading to 10.8 OSX I have upgraded the JDK and JRE to 7. I have updated the question once again. kindly have a look and let me know if I am going wrong anywhere. On running this command `/usr/libexec/java_home` I get
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: @Mark.. I see that the path is not retrieved from bashrc file. When I set JAVA_HOME from terminal separately only then I could able to build a project. Why could this be happening like this ? Any idea ?

Comment: That is a different question - using /usr/bin/java solves your original question

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44564303/5005676
If you see the mvn script: The code fails here ---

Steps for debugging and fixing:

Step 1: Open the mvn script /Users/Username/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin/mvn (Open with the less command like: less /Users/Username/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin/mvn)

Step 2: Find out the below code in the script:

```
  if [ -z "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
  if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME"  ] ; then
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
      # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
    else
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    fi
  else
    JAVACMD="`which java`"
  fi
fi

if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
  echo "Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly."
  echo "  We cannot execute $JAVACMD"
  exit 1
fi
```

Step3: It is happening because JAVACMD variable was not set. So it displays the error.

Note: To Fix it

```
export JAVACMD=Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

Key: If you want it to be permanent open emacs.profile

post the commands and press Ctrl-x Ctrl-c ( save-buffers-kill-terminal ).